# Xcode How to create git ignore multiple modules?

Tags: xcode, git

[this my multiple modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTp0U.png)

My question is should you gitignore multiple modules. how to fixed?

Is there a standard Xcode 5 git ignore file like the one listed here but for Xcode 5. I like this one because its comments explain every ignore file in detail for people who aren't as advanced like myself.

Comment: Until it's included in your repo folder, then yes, it can be by adding more configurations in `.gitignore` hidden file. Btw, Xcode 5 is too low, why do you use this version?